# Show a Icon in xfce4 panel when my script is running in background

Tags: bash, archlinux, xfce

Hi there I have xfce4 on manjaro.
I wrote A script to check if my VPN is disconnected, Connect that automaticly.
and made a desktop shortcut for that to run myscript in background.
is there any way to show an Icon in my xfce4 panel(or taskbar or whatever is its name) when script is running?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/348436